# How to store slider values in a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, slider

I'm using Matlab to create a GUI. Herefore I'm using the guide function of matlab.
I want to store the slider values in a vector. I am doing this in the callback function:

```
for i = 1:10
X(i) = get(handles.slider1,'Value');
end
```

But this results in a vector that stores the same value 10 times. What I actually want is to store the last 10 values of the slider in a vector. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a circular buffer: your array `X` has 10 elements, and in a separate variable you store the current position. In your callback, you increment (and go back to 1 once over 10) your current position and write the slider position to `X(current_pos)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a `1 x 10` vector of zeros when starting the GUI, i.e. in the `OpeningFcn` of the GUI:

```
handles.X = zeros(1,10);
guidata(hObject,handles);        % Update handles variable
```

Then in the Callback function of the slider, you always shift the vector one to the right and add the new value in the first place:

```
x =  get(handles.slider1,'Value');
handles.X = [x, handles.X(1:end-1)];
guidata(hObject,handles);         % Update handles variable
```

Now `X` always contains the last 10 values of the slider value, `X(1)` is the last value and so on.

Before the slider hasn't been moved 10 times, some of the values will not be correct, i.e. they will just be zero. If this is a problem, you could grow the `X` vector dynamically in the Callback.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I keep getting an error on handles.X = [x, X(1:end-1)]; –  PlatonInc. 5 mins ago

Comment: Oh I made a small typing mistake. See the updated answer.